# Estimating the data transfer rate using the DMA

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, dma

An I/O device uses a 16-bit data bus. The CPU executes 2 x 10 ^ 9 instructions/second. An instruction uses 5 processor cycles; 3 cycles are used by the data bus. A read/write uses 1 CPU cycle.
If CPU is 80% utilised doing non I/O tasks, estimate data transfer rate.

My attempt:

1. 6 x 10^9 x 20/100 will give 1.2x10^9 available cycles for non I/O tasks
2. 1.2 x 10^9 x 3/5 will give 720 000 000 cycles available for data transfer
3. 720 000 000 x 16 will give 1.152 x 10^10 bits for every 3 cycles

Is this correct? Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

(720 000 000 / 3) * 16 is bits transferred per second.